# Make all black pixels transparent using CIImage

Tags: objective-c, core-image

I'm trying to get something akin to a color mask using exclusively CIImage filters.

Basically, I'm looking to make all black pixels transparent. I don't mind what color all the non-black pixels end up having, so long as they have maximum alpha.

The code I'm familiar with in Core Graphics to achieve this would look like:

```
// Convert black sections to transparent using a color mask
const CGFloat maskingColors[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
CGImageRef result = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image, maskingColors);
```

I've given it a shot in Core Image using a color matrix filter but it just sets `result` to `nil` since the CIVector values are greater than `1.0f`.

```
// Create color matrix filter
CIFilter *matrix = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];

// Set filter properties
[matrix setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[matrix setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1.0f Y:0.0f Z:0.0f W:0.0f] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
[matrix setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:1.0f Z:0.0f W:0.0f] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
[matrix setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:0.0f Z:1.0f W:0.0f] forKey:@"inputBVector"];
[matrix setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:255.0f Y:255.0f Z:255.0f W:0.0f] forKey:@"inputAVector"];

// Get the mapped image
CIImage *result = [matrix valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

*Note: For what it's worth, this is an OSX app.*

Comment: Do you need it a simple solution or the fastest? I've faced such problem once and I recommend you to use openGL for fast image redraw cos you can't just draw transparent pixels above.

Comment: Simple solution for now, but if you have hints on OpenGL that would be good too. Ideally we should keep everything within CIImage for the scope of this question (to help others as well).

Comment: did you take a look at the `CIFilter` `CIMaskToAlpha` or `CIColorMap`?

Comment: `CIMaskToAlpha` would work if we can get the original image in strict black/white-only (without gray). Open to suggestions of how this might be coded. `CIColorMap` maps to a gradient which I don't think is helpful in this circumstance.

Comment: is using a Custom CIFilter an option for you?

Comment: Sure, didn't know that was possible @JonathanCichon! Sounds cool.

Comment: i edited my answer and added a method which solves your problem using a Custome CIFIlter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

Solution using a (simple) Custom CIFilter. This Method only works on OSX, as iOS does not support Custom Filters:

The CIFilter subclass (more or less a copy of [Apple's How-To](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html)):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MaskFilter : CIFilter {
    CIImage *inputImage;
}

@end

@implementation MaskFilter

static CIKernel *maskFilterKernel = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    [CIFilter registerFilterName: @"MaskFilter"
                     constructor: (id)self
                 classAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Mask Filter", kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName,
                                   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    kCICategoryColorAdjustment,
                                    kCICategoryStillImage, kCICategoryInterlaced,
                                    kCICategoryNonSquarePixels,nil], kCIAttributeFilterCategories,
                                   nil]
     ];
}

+ (CIFilter *)filterWithName:(NSString *)name {
    CIFilter  *filter;
    filter = [[self alloc] init];
    return filter;
}

- (id)init {
    if(maskFilterKernel == nil) {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
        NSString *code = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"MaskFilter" ofType: @"cikernel"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *kernels = [CIKernel kernelsWithString:code];
        maskFilterKernel = [kernels objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return [super init];
}

- (CIImage *)outputImage {
    CISampler *src = [CISampler samplerWithImage: inputImage];
    return [self apply:maskFilterKernel, src, kCIApplyOptionDefinition, [src definition], nil];
}

@end
```

The Custom Kernel which does all the work (Filename: MaskFilter.cikernel)

```
kernel vec4 maskFilterKernel(sampler src) 
{
    vec4 t = sample(src, destCoord());
    t.w = (t.x == 0.0 ? (t.y == 0.0 ? (t.z == 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0) : 1.0) : 1.0);
    return t;
}
```

using the Filter works just like a build-in Filter:

```
CIFilter *filter = [MaskFilter filterWithName:@"MaskFilter"];
[filter setValue:ciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
CIImage *mask = [filter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
```

Adding a parameter to choose the color to use as mask-color should be no problem.

**OLD ANSWER**

With built-in methods and classes, I can only come up with this rather unelegant solution (which uses only Core Image filters):

```
// convert all colors so they are brighter or equal to 0.5, except black
CIFilter *binary = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
[binary setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[binary setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1 Y:1 Z:1 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
[binary setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1 Y:1 Z:1 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
[binary setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1 Y:1 Z:1 W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"];
[binary setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.49999 Y:0.49999 Z:0.49999 W:0] forKey:@"inputBiasVector"];
inputImage = [binary valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

// convert to black/white only colors
binary = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize"];
[binary setDefaults];
[binary setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[binary setValue:@2 forKey:@"inputLevels"];
inputImage = [binary valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

// get mask
CIFilter *mask = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMaskToAlpha"];
[mask setDefaults];
[mask setValue: inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Custom filters are opening up a world of possibilities for me :) Any hints on how to create a custom filter that outputs a single-pixel result like CIAreaMaximumAlpha?

Comment: You can define the output size to match something different than your input size. But as Core Image does not support dynamic loops (only loops with compile-time conditions) you will have to think about some smart reducing without information loss between the steps. Take a look at [this article Section 26.2.2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch26.html)

Answer (score 2):

It converts black to transparent and any other color to White

```
    func filteredImage(cgImage: CGImage) -> UIImage {
        if let matrixFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix") {
            matrixFilter.setDefaults()
            matrixFilter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let rgbVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0)
            let aVector = CIVector(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, w: 0)
            matrixFilter.setValue(rgbVector, forKey: "inputRVector")
            matrixFilter.setValue(rgbVector, forKey: "inputGVector")
            matrixFilter.setValue(rgbVector, forKey: "inputBVector")
            matrixFilter.setValue(aVector, forKey: "inputAVector")
            matrixFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")

            if let matrixOutput = matrixFilter.outputImage, let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(matrixOutput, from: matrixOutput.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }

        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Simpler that the accepted answer. @Rajesh you should set `CIVector(x: 1)` to `inputRVector`, `inputGVector` and `inputBVector`, and `CIVector(x: 0)` to `inputAVector` because `CIColorMatrix` only need 1 dimension vectors and will only read the first value. It happen to work in your case because black is 0 everywhere, but it is not semantically correct.